# Augmented Faces Sceneform 1.16

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

How can I use or what to use instead of AugmentedFaceNode class now in Sceneform 1.16 to develop a try on glasses/make up app in Android?
I tried to copy the class in my project but it can't find SkeletonNode class now.

I installed it in my project like explained here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-a-simple-augmented-reality-android-app/

Thank you!

Comment: It would be very difficult to transform that project into an augmented faces one. Why don't you just base your project on Google's official example? That is: arcore-android-sdk-1.23.0/samples/augmented_faces_java

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://kristisimakova.medium.com/try-on-makeup-with-augmented-faces-d2ade1906f90) tutorial it will really help you in this regard, also don't use 1.16 it's not recommended, try using 1.17.1 or 1.15